# Min-width: 100vh is working on mobile, but not on PC with 100% width/zoom

Tags: html, css

100vh works only on mobile, or if you make the width of the web browser narrower on PC. If you make the window/width at 100%. The image appears to grow too tall, and div class="mars" overflows the viewport.

Can't post any screenshots. So that's a bummer.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="mars">
                <img  class="mars" src="img/marshero.jpg">
                <div class="greet">
                    <a href="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/mars/overview/">
                        <p class="inf">Click here to learn more about Mars at solarsystem.nasa.gov</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="inline">
                        <li class="inline"><a href="../index.html">▶About me</a></li>
                        <li class="inline"><a href="ProductDesign/index.html">Product design</a></li>
                        <li class="inline"><a href="Research/index.html">Research</a></li>
                        <li class="inline"><a href="ProductDevelopment/index.html">Product development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

div.mars {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

img.mars {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* nav */

nav.menu {
    background-color: #f9eae2;
    padding: 16px;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
}

ul.inline {
    text-align: center;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

li.inline {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 16px;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
        display:list-item;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue and make sure the image doesn't grow too tall, here is the updated CSS code snippet for your img.mars class:

```
 img.mars {
flex: 1 0 auto;
max-width: 100%; /* Set the maximum width to 100% of the container */
max-height: 100%; /* Set the maximum height to 100% of the container */
width: auto; /* Allow the image to scale with the container width */
height: auto; /* Allow the image to scale with the container height */
object-fit: cover;
```

}

Comment: I've tried something similar. It doesn't work. The image will grow larger when I widen the browser from 90 to 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue of the image overflowing when the window width is at 100%, you can modify your CSS as follows:

```
div.mars {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden; /* Change from "auto" to "hidden" */

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Ensure the image covers the full viewport */
img.mars {
    width: 100%; /* Use 100% width to fit the viewport */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* Add a container for your content to prevent overflow */
.content-container {
    padding: 16px; /* Adjust the padding as needed */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding in element's total width */
}
```